# Custom permalink for specific category

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to create a custom permalink for a custom post type and have it only apply to a specific category. For example I want to change this URL from: http://www.example.com/events/event-name to http://www.example.com/webinars/event-name.

This is the code I have so far which doesn't work:

```
function change_webinar_links($permalink) {
    global $post;
    if(get_post_type() == 'tribe_events' && has_category('webinar', $post->ID)) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/webinars/' . $post->post_name  ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_action( 'init', 'webinar_rewrite_rule');
function webinar_rewrite_rule() {
    global $post;
    if ( has_category('webinar', $post->ID) ) {
        add_rewrite_rule( '^webinars/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?tribe_events=$matches[1]&post_type=tribe_events&name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on the WordPress forums. Here is the working code for those looking to do something similar:

`add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_webinar_links', 10, 2 );
function change_webinar_links( $link, $post) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'tribe_events' && tribe_event_in_category('webinar') ) {
        $link = trailingslashit( home_url('/webinars/' . $post->post_name  ) );
    }
    return $link;
}
add_action( 'init', 'webinar_rewrite_rule', 5);
function webinar_rewrite_rule() {

        add_rewrite_rule( '^webinars/([^/]+)', 'index.php?tribe_events=$matches[1]&post_type=tribe_events&name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}`